# next-auth firebase adapter, successful sign-in but session is null in client

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, next-auth

I am trying to use credential providers, fb, google with nexth-auth firebase adapter. the signin is successful but i am not able to access the session through getSession or useSession in web/front. its null. my implementation:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { FirestoreAdapter } from '@auth/firebase-adapter';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import axios from 'axios';
import { cert } from 'firebase-admin/app';
import { auth } from '../../../firebase-config/firebase';


export default NextAuth({
  session: {
    jwt: true,
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials) {
        return await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, credentials.email || '', credentials.password || '')
          .then(userCredential => {
            if (userCredential.user) {
              console.log('suersssfdsfs', userCredential.user);
              return userCredential.user;
            }
            return null;
          })
          .catch(error => (console.log(error)))
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log(error);
  });
      }
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    })
  ],
  adapter: FirestoreAdapter({
    credential: cert({
      projectId: redacted ,
      clientEmail: redacted ,
    }),
  })
})
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your server log?